# Extjs4 grid is not showing updated value on grid

Tags: grid, extjs4, editing

i am working in extjs4. I have gridview with cellEditing plugin used.Its working correctly. But after editing foldername its not showing newly updated name of folder on grid. I don't want to refresh store. i just want to show updated name on grid. I have tried as=

```
getGridPanelStore = getGridPanel.getStore();
folderId = id;
var newtitle = newUpdatedValue;
getRecord = getGridPanelStore.getById(id);
recordToUpdate = getGridPanelStore.indexOf(getRecord ).set('title',newtitle );
```

But it not setting new updated value on grid. So how to show updated value on grid after editing without loading whole store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this code actually work?

As far as I understand the method [**indexOf**](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-indexOf) of Ext.data.Store retrieves the index of the record inside the store as an **integer** thus calling **set('title', newTitle)** probably **will raise an exception** of the type *Uncaught TypeError: Object n has no method 'set'*

Besides that you don't need to load the whole store to get your grid updated, since views are bound to the stores they auto refresh anytime a store field changes, so it should work by changing the title property as follows:

```
gridStore = gridPanel.getStore();
record = gridStore.getById(recordId);
record.set('title', newTitle);
```

If value doesn't update that way, you should check if the target column doesn't have a custom renderer associated to it that can be changing the view output for that specific field in any way.

Comment: Thanx for reply sir. Yaa i have custom renderer for title as={name: 'title', type: 'string',
       convert: function(value,model){
         if(Ext.isEmpty(model.get('name'))) {
          return model.get('folderName');
         } else {
          return value;
         }  
        }
      },  ....So what changes i need to do additionally?

Comment: Probably it would be best to use "[renderer](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.grid.column.Column-cfg-renderer)" method. As far as I understand you show only the title if no name value has been set, did you check that it has a valid value?, may be the **if** is being evaluated always to false.